# Programmatically identify django foreignkey links but omit through tables

Tags: django, many-to-many

I asked a [question earlier to programmatically identity foreignkey links.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151360/programmatically-identify-django-foreignkey-links).

I found that the below code pulls all the one-to-many links:

```
yourModel._meta.get_all_related_objects()
```

The only problem I'm finding now though is that it also includes interemdiary tables that are going to many-to-many links.  So if I have the below model,

```
class Model_one(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=30)
    people = models.ManyToManyField('Model_two', blank=True, through='Association')
```

Instead of returning nothing, the code returns Association.  Is there a way to either specify "real" one-to-many links or otherwise omit through tables?  Even if I have to delete it manually from the returned yourModel._meta.get_all_related_objects()?

Another way to ask this: **How can I identify/isolate a link that is actually a "through" table?**

Answer (score 1):

You can test each item to see if it's in `_meta.get_all_related_many_to_many_objects()`:

```
related_m2ms = MyModel._meta.get_all_related_many_to_many_objects()
for related in MyModel._meta.get_all_related_objects():
     if related not in related_m2ms:
         # Do something here with only one-to-many relationships
```

Comment: I'm finding that the MyModel._meta.get_all_related_objects() only retrieves one-to-many relationships.  So although the MyModel._meta.get_all_related_many_to_many_objects() returns the many-to-many links that aren't through an intermediary table, comparing the simple many-to-many to the one-to-many isn't helpful.  the MyModel._meta.get_all_related_objects() returns all one-to-many including the "through" table.  How do I omit just the through table?

Answer (score 0):

Found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238504/how-to-distuingish-between-djangos-automatically-created-manytomany-through-mod) that led me in the right direction:

```
m2m_links =MyModel._meta.local_many_to_many
for r in m2m_links:
    if not r.rel.through._meta.auto_created:
        print r.rel.through._meta.object_name
```

This will give the name of the "through" tables